# Link List C++ in certain order

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, swap, singly-linked-list

I have to order a given link list 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 following the pattern low -> high -> low -> high -> low resulting in 1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5 -> 4.

I have coded this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

class linked_list
{
private:
    node *head,*tail;
public:
    linked_list()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }

    void add_node(int n)
    {
        node *tmp = new node;
        tmp->data = n;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = tmp;
            tail = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = tmp;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }

    node* getHead()
    {
        return head;
    }
};

int main()
{
    linked_list a;
    a.add_node(1);
    a.add_node(2);
    a.add_node(3);
    a.add_node(4);
    a.add_node(5);
    bool leave= false;
    int direction = 1;
    node* considered_node = new node(*(a.getHead()));
    while(true)
    {
        if (considered_node->next == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (direction*considered_node->next->data < direction*considered_node->data)
        {
            int t= direction*considered_node->next->data;
            int p = direction*considered_node->data;
            int tmp = considered_node->next->data;
            considered_node->next->data = considered_node->data;
            considered_node->data = tmp;
        }
        delete considered_node;
        considered_node = considered_node->next;
        direction = -1*direction;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I am committing a mistake in the way I am iterating over the link list and deleting the pointers to avoid leakage memory. I do not want to change the declaration of the link list just the for loop.

Comment: `delete considered_node;  considered_node = considered_node->next;` is Undefined Behavior because you access the memory after deleting it.

Comment: Not required but anyway should be just 1 to 1 comparison, so you should move at most each element 1 position. So I would like it to make it generable to any order

Comment: move your `delete considered_node;` after the for loop.

Comment: Also add `considered_node->next->data = considered_node->data;` before deleting the `considered_node` after finishing the for loop.

Comment: btw it's a "linked" list

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, be aware that there is a perfectly functional and well-tested linked list in the standard library, [std::forward_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list), as well as a doubly-linked list ([std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list)) and [std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), which is a kind of a list of arrays if you like. You would operate on those using [<algorithm>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I have tried to explain. See, https://ideone.com/PdBY6W.

```cpp
int direction = 1;

node* considered_node = new node(*(a.getHead()));
while(true)
{
    if (considered_node->next == NULL)
    {
        break;
    }

    // do not need else here
    if (direction*considered_node->next->data < direction*considered_node->data)
    {
        // do not need t and p
        // int t= direction*considered_node->next->data;
        // int p = direction*considered_node->data;
        int tmp = considered_node->next->data;
        considered_node->next->data = considered_node->data;
        considered_node->data = tmp;
    }

    // if you delete considered_node, then you can not access it's address
    // after deleting it. So comment the deletion
    // delete considered_node;
    considered_node = considered_node->next;
    direction = -1*direction;
}

// Notice after finishing the for loop, considered_node is now at the tail
// node of the list. So, before deleting considered_node move it's reference
// to the next node and then delete. Otherwise, if you delete without moving
// the reference, the deletion will delete the tail node, in which case the 
// list will be 1-> 3 -> 2 -> 5 -> 0.
considered_node = considered_node->next;
delete considered_node;

// now the list is 1-> 3 -> 2 -> 5 -> 4
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly the assignment then you need to reorder the list when the first node must be not greater than the second node and the second node must be not less than the third node and so on.

If so then there is no need to use the operator new to reorder the list.

Here is a demonstrative program. I made minor changes in the list definition. For example the structure node should be hidden from the user of the list. It should be defined as a private data member inside the list definition.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class linked_list
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        node *next;
    } *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;

public:
    linked_list() = default;

    void add_node( int data )
    {
        node *tmp = new node { data, nullptr };

        if ( head == NULL )
        {
            head = tail = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            tail = tail->next = tmp;
        }
    }

    void reorder()
    {
        int direction = 0;

        auto condition = [&direction]( const auto &a, const auto &b )
        {
            return ( direction ^= 1 ) ?  b < a : a < b;
        };

        node **current = &head;

        for ( ; *current && ( *current )->next; current = &( *current )->next )
        {
            if ( condition( ( *current )->data, ( *current )->next->data ) )
            {   
                node * &next = ( *current )->next;
                std::swap( *current, next );
                std::swap( ( *current )->next, next->next );
            }
        }

        tail = *current;
    }

    friend  std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, const  linked_list &list)
    {
        for ( const node *current = list.head; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
        {
            os << current->data << " -> ";
        }

        return os << "null";
    }   
};

int main() 
{
    linked_list list;
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for ( int data : a ) list.add_node( data );

    std::cout << list << '\n';

    list.reorder();

    std::cout << list << '\n';

    int b[] = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    for ( int data : b ) list.add_node( data );

    std::cout << list << '\n';

    list.reorder();

    std::cout << list << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5 -> 4 -> null
1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5 -> 4 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> null
1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5 -> 4 -> 7 -> 6 -> 9 -> 8 -> 10 -> null
```

Pay attention to that after reordering the list you have to adjust the pointer tail of the list. Otherwise adding new elements to the list can be invalid.

Comment: I have a doubt regarding pure C++ programming. What dies this line do?
 node **current = &head;
head is a pointer so you get the address of a pointer and you save it to some ** that what it means? Thanks a lot

Comment: @HectorEstebanCabezos Yes there is a pointer to pointer. It means that you are dealing the pointer head by reference (in C meaning) indirectly through a pointer.

Comment: @HectorEstebanCabezos Imagine that you had write for example  node *current = head; In this case if you will change the value of the variable current as for example current = nullptr; the value of the variable head will not be changed. But if you will write node **current = &head; then in this statement *current =  nullptr; the value of the pointer head will be changed to nullptr.

Comment: @HectorEstebanCabezos It is similar to the following. int x = 10; int y = x; y = 20; As you see the value of the variable x will not be changed. But if you will write int x = 10; int *y = &x; *y = 20; It is the variable x that will be changed.

Comment: Oh my god thank a lot, I need to process this information because it is not that easy for me to digest it

Comment: @HectorEstebanCabezos Yes, it is not easy to understand when you have no enough experience.

Comment: This comes basically from the idea that even though we are dealing with pointers if you do node *current = head you are kind of copying a pointer by value while if you do **current = &head you have a reference to the pointer. Then doing *current=nullptr means assign move the pointer pointed by current to nullptr correct? Last question, what is the exact explanation of node * &next

Comment: Last question, what is the exact explanation of node * &next

Comment: @HectorEstebanCabezos This declares a reference to pointer to node.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt again, I promise is the last one but I have tried for quite a long to debug and understand this part and still looks like magic:
                node * &next = ( *current )->next;
                std::swap( *current, next );
                std::swap( ( *current )->next, next->next );
I know how to do swap with references but I do not understand this way

Comment: @HectorEstebanCabezos You have to swap the pointers to the two node themselves and also to swap their data members next This call std::swap( *current, next ); swaps the pointers themselves and this call std::swap( ( *current )->next, next->next ) swap their data members next.

Comment: After the first swap &next has value 2 and &next->next is 2 as well and like that until infinite. So for the last swap, when swapping next->next (which has data 2 and points to next of data 2) with (*current)->next, whose data is 4 after 5 and so on. How when you swap the &next->next data gets to 4 if before was pointing the whole time to data 2

Comment: @HectorEstebanCabezos Let's assume that the list has two nodes head = |A| -> |A|B| ->|B|nullptr|. After the first swap you have head = |B|  |A|A| |B|nullptr|. After the second swap you have  head = |B| |A|nullptr| |B||A| Now just rewrite the picture according to the pointer references head = |B| -> |B|A| -> |A|nullptr|